# Инициализация и заполнение массива

Tags: массивы, objective-c

```
4. Write a “Metropolis” class. It should contain the following:
Variable:
array of 10 cities.
Instance method:
createCity:atIndex:withPopulation: (single method) which creates a city with first parameter being a name at index (from the second parameter) and sets its population to that of third parameter. So, you should be able to do this:
[myMetropolis createCity: @”Almaty” atIndex: 2 withPopulation: 1500000]
```

Не очень понимаю как это сделать.
Вот мои наброски:

```
@interface Metropolis:NSObject{
  NSMutableArray * newArray;
}
-(void)createMassive;
-(void)createCity:(NSString *)nameSeccond andindex: (int) atIndex andpopulation: (int) withPopulation;
@end

////////////////////////////////
@implementation Metropolis
-(void)createMassive{
  newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
-(void)createCity:(NSString *)nameSeccond andindex: (int) atIndex andpopulation: (int) withPopulation{
  [newArray initWithObjects:nameSeccond, withPopulation,nil];
}
@end

Metropolis * mt = [[Metropolis alloc]init];
[mt createMassive];
[mt createCity:@"Minks" andindex:1 andpopulation:1600000];
NSLog(@"massiv%@", [mt newarray]);
```

Тут однозначно что-то не так) Объясните пожалуйста что делаю не так?

Comment: [newArray initWithObjects:nameSeccond, withPopulation,nil];
Че это за хрень? По мне дак этот метод возвращает результат и то после аллокейшена.

Comment: да, согласен. Тут вообще несуразица. Но в том-то и проблема. Я не могу понять как сделать двумерный массив.
Что бы записи выглядели примерно так
Minsk,1600000
Moscow,11000000
...

Comment: NSDictionary

Comment: Можно с примером, если не сложно, конечно?

Answer (score 1):

Вот еще современней для objective-c вариант (бедные obj-c программисты, которые не видели мир, кончают от счастья ^_^):

```
NSArray *cityes = @[@[@"Moscow", @12345], @[@"Moscow", @12345], @[@"Moscow", @12345]];
NSLog(@"%@", cityes);
NSLog(@"%@", cityes[0]);
```

с iOS6 поддержка. Что касается массиво с визвестным размером, то после аллокешена памяти нужно забить ее нулевыми объектами.

```
#import "Metropolis.h"
@implementation Metropolis
{
    NSMutableArray *cityesArrays;
}
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        cityesArrays = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            [cityesArrays addObject:[NSNull null]];
        }
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)createCity:(NSString *)city atIndex:(NSUInteger)index withPopulation:(NSNumber *)population
{
    NSArray *cityInfo = @[city, population];
    [cityesArrays replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:cityInfo];

#ifdef DEBUG
    NSLog(@"****\nDEBUG: %s [Line %d] \n%s:%d \nTRACE: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, __FILE__, __LINE__, cityesArrays);
#endif
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть пару способов, выбирайте то что больше подходит для вашего конкретного случая

```
NSMutableDictionary *myArray = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[myArray setObject: @"value1" forKey: @"key1"];
[myArray setObject: @"value2" forKey: @"key2"];

[myArray objectForKey: @"key1"];
```

или

```
NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"key1", @"key2", nil];
NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"value1", @"value2", nil];

NSMutableDictionary *mayArray = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects: values forKeys: keys];
[myArray objectForKey: @"key1"];
```

Comment: Такие примеры я видел. И это понятно. Мне не понятно как выполнить задание, написанное мной в первом посте. Это задание из видеокурса по objective-c. И очень хотелось бы понять, как сделать так, что бы в методе createCity можно было записать в массив nameSeccond и withPopulation, который передаются в метод createCity. Пока для меня это тупик. Поэтому прошу помощи...

Comment: Вам необходимо просто знать, что в массив в Objective-C можно вносить только объекты. Примитивные значения типа int туда нельзя вносить. Сначала нужно все примитивы (int в вашем случае) привести к объекту (NSNumber например).